# Connect TFS to GitKraken

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, gitkraken

I'm currently designing an WPF / C # project under visual studio. So I have a TFS server as source manager and stories management. This one is also in connection with TeamCity.

Nowadays given the very bad management of the version branches since tfs, I would like to pass by real tool that GitKraken (or others that would be compatible).

The problem is that I do not know what URL applied in Gitkraken knowing that my repositories are not Git ...

the URL: https://[Name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/[ProjectName] does not work or at least the following error is returned :

"Could not connect to 'origin'. Double-check your remote url, then make sure you have access to do action..."

Can a software such as GitKraken connect via TFS without it being a Git server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not able to directly use TFVC repo with GitKraken. One way to do the trick is migrating the TFVC repo to GIT repo.

*TFS2017update2* provides a simple [migration tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/2017/mar-29-team-services#import-repositories-from-tfvc-to-git) to migrate from Team Foundation Version Control to Git. Individual folders or branches can be imported to the Git repository, or the entire TFVC repository can be imported (minus the branches). Users can also import up to 180 days of history.

For changing TFVC to GIT, some limitation please refer this tutorial:[Migrate from TFVC to Git](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/)

On earlier TFS version, you could use [Git-TF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) command line tool.

Comment: thanks, effectively after migrating to a Git Repo, Now I can manage my branches serenely !

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, GitKraken (like other Git GUI tools) works solely with [Git](https://git-scm.com/).  If you are using the older Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), then you will NOT be able to use GitKraken to manage the branches within the repository.

UPDATE: I am not aware of any tools similar to GitKraken for using with TFVC.

Comment: therefore in all cases, i have to switch my repo to git repo from tfs ? or if you know of a similar software being compatible for TFVC?

Comment: If I switch from TFVC to Git, will my VCS root name / ID login always work? I think in my case at TeamCity

Answer (score 2):

Like others have mentioned before, GitKraken is a Git client tool and your repository is TFS. So I suggest migrating your source code from TFS to Git. I recommend using the [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) tool with the following command:

For migrating the whole history of all the branches:

`git tfs clone https://tfs.codeplex.com:443/tfs/Collection $/project/trunk . --branches=all`

For migrating the history of only the main branch:

`git tfs clone https://tfs.codeplex.com:443/tfs/Collection $/project/trunk . --branches=none`